# Лошадь, дверь, дочь - окончание МИ или ЯМИ?

Tags: грамматика

Какова история окончаний МИ/ЯМИ для слов "лошадь, дочь, дверь"? Откуда взялось окончание МИ и какая из форм старается подвинуть другую? И наконец, можно ли предположить наличие разных смысловых оттенков для этих окончаний? Например, собирательное или обобщенное окончание для МИ и конкретное  значение для АМИ.

К примеру: не надо хлопать дверьми (вообще не надо этого делать) - не хлопай дверями (именно сейчас и именно этими). Или: мы любовались лошадями - с лошадьми надо уметь обращаться.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Грамота,ру  говорит,что
варианты окончания творительного падежа мн. числа -ами (-ями) / -(ь)ми в древности принадлежали разным типам склонения имен существительных. Однако после унификации склонения существительных во множественном числе для всех слов нормативным стало окончание -ами (-ями). И лишь у нескольких слов в современном русском языке возможно окончание -(ь)ми. У слова дети форма детьми единственно возможная. В парах дверями – дверьми, лошадями – лошадьми, дочерями – дочерьми возможны оба варианта, причем более употребительно окончание -(ь)ми. У слова звери предпочтительным считается форма зверями; вариант зверьми рассматривается как устаревающий. Кроме этого, у слов кость и плеть при нормативных формах костями, плетями формы на -(ь)ми сохраняются в устойчивых сочетаниях лечь костьми, бить плетьми.

Про конкретное и собирательное значения ничего нет,мне как-то ближе форма лошадьми, дочерьми,дверьми без оттенков. Дочерями вообще воспринимаю как разговорное.

http://gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search_answer/?s=%E4%E2%E5%F0%FC%EC%E8

Answer (score 4):

Мои преподаватели говорили "дочерьми", "дверьми". Только так,  не различая каких-либо оттенков. Я воспринимаю такое произношение устаревающим.
Вот что пишет Розенталь в "Практической стилистике":

```
  "Некоторые существительные 3 склонения  имеют вариантные формы: дверями -дверьми, дочерями - дочерьми, лошадями - лошадьми.
```

Древнейшей была форма на -ьми, оказавшая влияние на соответствующую форму существительных других типов склонения и вытеснившая у них первоначальное окончание -ами/-ями. Однако с середины XIX века формы на -ьми постепенно убывают, сохраняясь лишь в немногих словах в качестве стилистических вариантов. Причем архаичная форма стала, наоборот, более употребительной и разговорной"

Answer (score 1):

Подобный вопрос уже был, и там в ходе обсуждения пришли к выводу, что можно и так, и так. Но, как мне кажется, тут надо смотреть в зависимости от слова, что чаще употребляется. Например, "лошадьми" звучит лучше, чем "лошадями", а вот "дочерями" — лучше, чем "дочерьми" (хотя слово "дочерями" Ворд подчеркивает как ошибку).

Comment: О смысловых оттенках окончаний я задумалась когда увидела запись "Продаются открытки с лошадями", и мне она показалась лучше, чем "с лошадьми". Много открыток, а на каждой открытке по лошадке. А если "с лошадьми", то на одной открытке должно быть много лошадок. Но почему-то никто этих оттенков не замечает - возможно, их просто нет. А каков, с вашей точки зрения,  прогноз на употребление МИ/ЯМИ в будущем?